# c++ Straustrup calculator02.cpp function Error

Tags: function, class, c++17

I have a small problem with the `functions` inside `calculator02.cpp`
there is an `error` when compile the code

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]130 | }

Yes I know that in any case function must `return` the `value` what can I do to solve this problem? in this case I do not have any more cases apart from that ones inside the `function` itself, same with the `get` function;

```
Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full) {       // do we already have a Token ready?
        // remove token from buffer
        full = false;
        return buffer;
    }

    char ch;
    cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

    switch (ch) {
    case ';':    // for "print"
    case 'q':    // for "quit"
    case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': case '}': case '{':
        return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '9':
    {
        cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
        double val;
        cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
        return Token('8', val);   // let '8' represent "a number"
    }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
    }
}
double primary()
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '(':    // handle '(' expression ')'
    {
        double d = expression();
        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != ')') error("')' expected");
            return d;
    }
    case '{':
        {
         double d = expression();
         t = ts.get();
         if(t.kind != '}') error("'}' Expected");
            return d;   
        }
    case '8':            // we use '8' to represent a number
        return t.value;  // return the number's value
    default:
        error("primary expected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Some cases in your Token_stream::get() function dont return anything and you dont have a general return at the end (which could fix your issue)

Comment: So i believe you just have to add returns to your default cases

Comment: in both functions

Comment: Yes but I don't need default because there are only that cases written above

Comment: But you have a default case declared in both functions

Comment: What does `error` do?

Comment: Does `error` return to its caller?

Comment: ok I solved the problem with just adding `return -1;` after `error` and that's all return doesn't meter in case of `error` occurred thank you all,